# Distribution List Outlook(contact Group) import and Export

Tags: c#, list, outlook, distribution, contacts

I'm creating an app to import and export contacts from outlook, export and import could but I can not export the contact groups.

I need my app to import and export contact groups.
my idea is to have 2 apps, one that exports to other file and import it from a file.

I could do this only with the contacts, but need to do with the groups too.

someone has an idea how to do in C #?

-------------------------------------------------------Extra---------------------------------------------

I'm trying to backup the contact groups that I created in my outlook to send to other people who want this group.

for example
I have group

FULANOS

where the member has

falano1@email.com

falano2@email.com

falano3@email.com

falano4@email.com

so I want to back up his outlook extracting it. Extracts of my contacts and I have created a csv file and app client downloads this file and automatically updates outlook of customers.

Now I do the same thing but with contact groups.
[image: app function]

For common contacts the app already does that now takes to the groups. It exports and imports.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to get from the distribution list?  Are you just trying to extract a list of SMTP addresses?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".